# WebStorm TypeScript decorator new line

Tags: typescript, webstorm, decorator

I am using WebStorm IDE (2017.1.3 by JetBrains) and with TypeScript (.ts) files and changes and reformat my decorators.

```
@Input() str: string;
```

And he reformats in to this:

```
@Input()
str: string;
```

And I can not find anywhere in my settings where it does that, I want to keep it on one line. How/where to change this setting?

Screenshot:

[image: My current IDE settings (screenshot)]

Comment: Please always state your IDE version (ideally with build numbers). **P.S.** So it's WebStorm or IntelliJ? Those are two different products (IntelliJ contains all what WebStorm does). Just to avoid confusion.

Comment: Sorry I thought IntelliJ was the manufacturer, but it is JetBrains. I changed the topic description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update your IDE. As of **2017.3** it [should leave decorators as is](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21121#comment=27-2397394) (does not force any style). Latest version is **2018.2** (released last week).

For actually forcing preferred style -- watch https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21121 ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

Comment: Thank you LazyOne